# How to create a table sub header for only one header of all the headers in html

Tags: html, html-table

Hi I have to create a table like below image.

[image]
Please help me to get that table. I am working on angular 4 project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can merge cells width [`colspan`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) (horizontally) and [`rowspan`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp) (vertically) attributes in HTML.

So you can create 2 rows for the header. In those columns where there are no subheaders, use `rowspan=2` to merge vertically. Where there are two rows in the header, use `colspan=X` in the first row to merge horizontally above the subheaders:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
th {
  background: grey;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Simple header</th>
    <th colspan="2">Combo header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- skip 1st column because it merges vertically -->
    <th>Sub 1</th>
    <th>Sub 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```